# I can't delete files of USB device in samsung galaxy grand neo in ubuntu

Tags: linux, usb, usb-drive

I cant delete files/Images in mobile as above mentioned. Whenever I delete particular file/image it shows a dialog containing error that

> libmtp error:  could not delete object.

Comment: In its current form, it's not clear whether your question is about programming, or whether you're trying to delete files using existing capabilities of the phone. Please [edit] your question to clarify that, so that it can help future users with similar problems.

Comment: @Mogsdad i clarify that in ubantu not programatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

```
lsb_release -a
```

Perhaps you do not have the right `MTP` packages installed on your system?

Try with:

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-server libmtpserver-dev
```

and reconnect.

Also I've seen cases when it failed and renaming the file did the job (kinda strange). In case you want to go that way.

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.....!!1